# watch on $router.query not firing in IE

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have written a watcher on queryString. am updating the query on anchor tag click. Not sure my watcher not listing in this case. If I update query string on button click watcher working. can anyone help me with

[Here is jsfiddle for reference](http://%20%20%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/willjosefi/4shd27gm/9/)

I am using vue version: 2.6.7

Answer (score 0):

I just found [solution](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1911#issuecomment-376880972) here. There is no direct solution available, need to write an extra watcher to achieve this.

Thanks